# Neurolab newff output range and different results from network

Tags: neural-network

I realized that the newff output is fixed to range [-1, 1] and I do the following to test how should output outside the range work.

```
import neurolab as nl
import numpy as np

# Create train samples
x = np.linspace(-7, 7, 20)
y = x * 10

size = len(x)

inp = x.reshape(size,1)
tar = y.reshape(size,1)

norm_inp = nl.tool.Norm(inp)
inp = norm_inp(inp)

norm_tar = nl.tool.Norm(tar)
tar = norm_tar(tar)

# Create network with 2 layers and random initialized
# as I normalized the inp, the input range is set to [0, 1] (BTW, I don't know how
#to norm it to [-1, 1])
net = nl.net.newff([[0, 1]],[5, 1])

# Train network
error = net.train(inp, tar, epochs=500, show=100, goal=0.02)

# Simulate network
out = norm_tar.renorm(net.sim([[ 0.21052632 ]]))

print "final output:-----------------"
print out

inp before norm
[[-7.        ]
 [-6.26315789]
 [-5.52631579]
 [-4.78947368]
 [-4.05263158]
 [-3.31578947]
 [-2.57894737]
 [-1.84210526]
 [-1.10526316]
 [-0.36842105]
 [ 0.36842105]
 [ 1.10526316]
 [ 1.84210526]
 [ 2.57894737]
 [ 3.31578947]
 [ 4.05263158]
 [ 4.78947368]
 [ 5.52631579]
 [ 6.26315789]
 [ 7.        ]]

tar before norm
[[-70.        ]
 [-62.63157895]
 [-55.26315789]
 [-47.89473684]
 [-40.52631579]
 [-33.15789474]
 [-25.78947368]
 [-18.42105263]
 [-11.05263158]
 [ -3.68421053]
 [  3.68421053]
 [ 11.05263158]
 [ 18.42105263]
 [ 25.78947368]
 [ 33.15789474]
 [ 40.52631579]
 [ 47.89473684]
 [ 55.26315789]
 [ 62.63157895]
 [ 70.        ]]
```

I expect the out to be around -40 after renorm for the input 0.21052632
but the results are not repeatable, sometimes is right (around -40) but sometimes is wrong (become -70).

I am wondering why the training results are not stable and is there a better way to train a nn that produce output value out range [-1, 1]

Answer (score 2):

There are different training method for "newff". According to [library](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/lib.html), you could use 7 different train function. Try to use different train function. [Here](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_props.html) is the example about change network property. Here is the example.

```
import neurolab as nl
# Create 
net = nl.net.newff([[-1, 1]], [5, 1])
# Default train function (train_gdx) 
print net.trainf  # Trainer(TrainGDX)
# Change train function
net.trainf = nl.train.train_bfgs
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Think you @apaul34208, this is the first time I answer a question. I've made some change on it.